# Best way to code lazy loading outside the model in vanilla c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, lazy-initialization

I have to implement a LazyLoading on the properties of my Entites Class. I can't use any framework and external dll (nugets package are forbiden, I can't use Entity Framework or Castle Dynamic Proxy Interceptors).

My actual solution is to use decorators that override the properties and do the lazy loading.

```
public class StudentEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public virtual SchoolEntity School { get; set; }
}

  public class StudentEntityLazyLoadingDecorator : StudentEntity
{
    private readonly SchoolService _schoolService;
    private readonly StudentEntity _studentEntity;
    private SchoolEntity _school;

    public StudentEntityLazyLoadingDecorator(SchoolService schoolService, StudentEntity studentEntity)
    {
        _schoolService = schoolService;
        _studentEntity = studentEntity;
    }

    public override SchoolEntity School
    {
        get
        {
            if (_school == null)
            {
                _school = _schoolService.Get();
            }

            return _school;
        }
        set
        {
            _school = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know a better way to do this in vanilla c# ? I want to separate the lazy loading code from my Entity code.

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation is correct, but it's a wheel that did not need to be reinvented. There's a `Lazy<T>` class that already provides this functionality.

[MSDN link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-5.0)

```
var myLazySchool = new Lazy<SchoolEntity>( () => {
    Console.WriteLine("Fetching school...");
    return _schoolService.Get();
});

var a = myLazySchool.Value;  // <-- writes message to console
var b = myLazySchool.Value;  // <-- no message
var c = myLazySchool.Value;  // <-- no message
```

The method you pass into the lazy object's constructor will be executed the first time you try to access its `Value`. After that, the object just caches the value.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not thread-safe. The existence check and the retrieval of data are two separate methods. So they are not treated as one, atomic method, which might result multiple calls of data retrieval.

You have several options, just to name of few:

#### Double-check locking

```cs
private readonly object lockObject = new object();
public override SchoolEntity School
{
    get
    {
        if (_school == null)
        {
            lock(lockObject)
            {
                if(_school == null)
                {
                    _school = _schoolService.Get();
                }
            }
        }

        return _school;
    }
}
```

It is [quite easy to implement this in a wrong way](https://www.sudhanshutheone.com/posts/double-check-lock-csharp) and its performance might not be as good as the other alternatives. It is NOT recommended.

#### `LazyInitializer`

```cs
private SchoolEntity _school;
private object lockObject = new object();
private readonly Lazy<SchoolEntity> school = LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _school, ref lockObject, () => _schoolService.Get());
public override SchoolEntity School
{
    get
    {
        return school;
    }
}
```

Here the existence check is done by the `LazyInitializer` but you need to allocate a backing field and a lock object to make sure that the data is not initialized multiple times.

#### `Lazy<T>`

```cs
private readonly Lazy<SchoolEntity> _school = new Lazy<SchoolEntity>(() => _schoolService.Get(), true);
public override SchoolEntity School
{
    get
    {
        return _school.Value;
    }
}
```

Here the `Lazy<T>` does almost everything on your behalf.